# SQL: Need to create two unique records for each single record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, duplicate-data

The simple question is how can you take a set of records with a PK and create exactly two records for each source with a slightly altered key for the duplicate?  In other words, I take 4000 records and produce 8000 records where 4000 are identical and the other 4000 have a slightly altered key.  I cannot do a union because this is essentially two selects (long story).

The rest gets complicated, but maybe necessary to provide examples.

This is my original set (it contains over 4000 records)

```
dateGroup areaGroup itemID editionID
   1          1        1       1
   1          1        1       2
   1          2        1       1
   1          2        2       1

   2          1        1       1
   2          1        1       2
   2          2        1       1
   2          2        1       2
```

For each record I need to create a duplicate record ganging the areaGroups together under '0', then create a comma separated list of original areaGroups as a separate field.  (The "why" is some dumb programmer (me) made a mistake about 15 years ago.)  I can renumber the editionIDs as necessary, but the original and duplicate record must have the same editionID (thus why a union wouldn't work).  The PK remains the same as above (all fields)

```
dateGroup areaGroup itemID editionID aGroups
   1          0        1       1        1
   1          0        1       2        1
   1          0        1       1        2    // Duplicate (EditionID)
   1          0        2       1        2
   2          0        1       1        1
   2          0        1       2        1
   2          0        1       1        2    // Duplicate (EditionID)
   2          0        1       2        2
```

The end result would renumber the editionID as needed to make the record unique.

```
dateGroup areaGroup itemID editionID aGroups  (EditionID is what is altered)
   1          0        1       1        1
   1          0        1       2        1
   1          0        1       2        2    1 changed to 2 (one more than row 1)
   1          0        2       1        2
   2          0        1       1        1
   2          0        1       2        1
   2          0        1       2        2    1 changed to 2 (one more than row 1)
   2          0        1       2        2

   1          1        1       1
   1          1        1       2
   1          2        1       2             1 changed to 2 (editionID) to match
   1          2        2       1

   2          1        1       1
   2          1        1       2
   2          2        1       2             1 changed to 2 to match above
   2          2        1       2
```

I know you could calculate the editionID like a row rank like so:

```
select row_number() over ( 
       partition by dateGroup, itemID 
       order by dateGroup, itemID) as editionID
```

So all I need is to know how to duplicate the records from a single set

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you want. You say each row should have a duplicate but then in your example you only have two duplicates. Can you list out exactly what results you want from your sample data? Is the aGroups supposed to be 1 for the original and 2 for the duplicate? What do you mean by 'one more than row 1'?

Comment: The third example is the result I expect.  The areaGroup of 0 set moves the areaGroup value to the aGroups value (comma separated set, but there's only one value).  Essentially, the only difficulty is if we need to change the editionID to make these unique, then we need to reflect that edition change in the original list.  I don't see how we could do this without starting from a single set (no unions).

Comment: It's still really hard to understand what you want. Why do you want to 'renumber' EditionID? Can you say exactly how you want to calculate the 'renumbered' EditionID? You say 'the original and duplicate record must have the same editionID' but then you want to renumber them? In your example output it's hard to work out which rows relate to which original rows. Maybe put an 'OriginalRowId' column in just to clarify this.

Comment: Originally, each areaGroup had its own copy of items (redundant). To remove duplicates, we stored all items in a single areaGroup with an extra comma separated list of areaGroups which that item participated.  In order to resolve slight differences in items between areaGroups, we duplicated an item, incremented its edition, and updated the areaGroup field list. Since we rewrote the entire mess. However, we still have customers using it. In order to write code that "shrinks" the duplicate products across areaGroups, I need to duplicate a single row into two with a single select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`

**UDPATE**  perhaps I misunderstood the problem and I thought you were having a problem with the union loosing the duplicates.

If the problem is that you want to do a row_number over a union why don't you do somthing like

```
select row_number() over ( 
       partition by dateGroup, itemID 
       order by dateGroup, itemID) as editionID
FROM
(

         SELECT 

              dateGroup, itemID
          FROM TableA
          UNION ALL 
         SELECT 

              dateGroup, itemID
          FROM TableB 
) Data
```

Comment: The format of the code in this answer solved the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

do a cross join on a derived table: 
 ( select 1 as aGroups union all select 2 )

Comment: I think the essential problem here is that the row_number() would alter the editionID in the first select, which needs to reflect in the second select's editionID.  Thus, why I couldn't use a union.

Comment: with a cross join on a derived table you shouldn't need row_number().

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a temporary table with duplicates and their count.
Then I'd filter the original table to have only unique rows, and insert another row for each row in the temporary table, incrementing their editionID.

In MySQL, I'd use user @variables; not sure about MS SQL.

Comment: So far so good.  It would be nice to do it in one shot rather than using a cursor over thousands of records.